# Babel deoptimises styling of big files in ember.js app

Tags: javascript, ember.js, babeljs

I have an ember.js app with a big file that started to have this problem:

> [Babel: notes > applyPatches][BABEL] Note: The code generator has
> deoptimised the styling of
> /home/user/code/notes-frontend/notes/components/model-wps/edit.js as
> it exceeds the max of 500KB.

Although the functionality is not affected, this makes it impossible to debug as Babel won't print the file nicely.

I've seen that setting babel `compact` option to `false` should solve my problem, but I can't make that configuration work in my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After asking the Ember Community Discord, they suggested to enable source maps in ember-cli-babel ([ref here](https://github.com/babel/ember-cli-babel#enabling-source-maps)).

In ember-cli-build.js, just add the option:

```
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  babel: {
    sourceMaps: 'inline'
  }
});
```

And now you will be able to debug your source code even after files are transpiled by babel.